# Movement of paddle not working

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

Just going through some tutorials for learning Unity. I am on the 2nd video atm of the series and the video is covering the movement of the player, where the game it's based on is Pong.

The tutor is using JavaScript and has written some code that appears to work to make the Paddle move up and down. I however am using C# and have come across errors such as `cannot reference UnityEngine.Component.rigidbody2D`, etc. Now I have got rid of that error/bug and haven't got any errors atm however it's still not working.

As I am new to Unity, could someone just help me out with this please. I am sure it's something very simple, however I am not yet familiar with the Unity code base. The code I have written is below.

***Btw... I re-added the Start method as a solution elsewhere mentioned about solving a problem like this by using the Start method... even though in the video the tutor guy says to get rid of it***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour {

public KeyCode moveUp, moveDown;
public float speed = 10;
public Vector2 v;

//Used for Initialising
void Start()
{
    v = rigidbody2D.velocity;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKey(moveUp))
    {
        v.y = speed;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(moveDown))
    {
        v.y = speed * - 1;

    }
    else
    {
        v.y = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Link to video I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCysoAoV3dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing the velocity of your rigid body. You are changing another arbitrary vector `v`.

Yes, in your `Start()` you say `v = rigidbody2D.velocity;` but that only assigns the current velocity of the rigid body to `v`. If you subsequently change `v`, you're changing just that, and not the velocity of the original rigid body.

So change your update to

```
v = rigidbody2D.velocity; //you might be able to skip this in your case
v.y = speed;
rigidbody2D.velocity = v;
```

and do something similar for the other lines, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yea... i understand what you mean.... lol that was silly of me not to see that in the first place. Thanks